# Line with parametric equations?

Tags: linear-algebra

We were given a task in tutorials to solve the following question for extension after the normal segment:

Let *W* be the line with parametric equations *x = 2t, y = −t, z = 4t*;

(a) Find a basis for *W*.

(b) Find the standard matrix for the orthogonal projection on *W*.

(c) Use the matrix from part (b) to find the orthogonal projection of a point (x0,y0,z0) on *W*.

(d) Find the distance between (2, 1, −3) and the line *W*.

I'm flat out for ideas, the only thing I could think of is placing it in vector form and then possibly multiplying by the identity matrix so that the basis could be extended.

Also the question comes from the textbook Elementary Linear Algebra 10th edition, chapter 6 under the 6.4 set of questions, question 16, if that helps at all.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your idea of transform it to vector form is correct. It gives you the basis
$$\begin{pmatrix}x\\y\\z \end{pmatrix}=t\begin{pmatrix}2\\-1\\4 \end{pmatrix}$$

So the basis is
\begin{pmatrix}2\\-1\\4 \end{pmatrix}

To find the standard matrix of projection, you need to find the projection of 
$$\begin{pmatrix}1\\0\\0 \end{pmatrix}, \begin{pmatrix}0\\1\\0 \end{pmatrix},\begin{pmatrix}0\\0\\1 \end{pmatrix}$$
onto $W$. The result will form the columns of the standard matrix.

So part (c) is easily solved.

For part (d), you can find the projection first, the difference of the vector and its projection would be the vector that starts from the point and is normal to the line. So the norm of that vector is the distance.

**Edit**: For part (b), as abel pointed out in the comment, the orthogonal projection matrix can be easily found by $uu^T/(u^Tu)$ where $u$ is the direction vector of the line.

Comment: you could find the projection matrix at once if you use $uu^\top /u^\top u$ with $u = (2, -1, 4.)^\top$

Comment: @abel: Thanks for pointing that out. I thought there should be an easier way, but couldn't remember.

Comment: you are welcome. you must be a good teacher.

Comment: @abel: Thank you. I try. Practicing on MSE helps!